# how to make select tag to have by default current year and current month?

Tags: grails, select

i have 2 select tags as,

```
 <td><g:select name="Year" from="${2004..2014}"  optionValue="${Year}" /></td>
  <td><g:select name="Month" from="${['January','February','March','April','May','Jun','July','August','September','October','November','December']}"  optionValue="${month}"  /></td>
```

Now i want in gsp it should display me the current year and month in select box of year and month instead of displaying first year and month in list ..

how to achieve it?..can any one answer me please.

advance thanks
Laxmi

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
<g:set var="months" value="${new java.text.DateFormatSymbols().months}"/>
<g:set var="today" value="${new Date()}"/>

<td><g:select name="Year" from="${2004..2014}" value="${today[Calendar.YEAR]}" /></td>

<td><g:select name="Month" from="${months as List}" 
    value="${months[today[Calendar.MONTH]]}"  /></td>
```

Comment: thank you..I used it to display only month..for year i used date picker..as,

Comment: '<td><g:datePicker name="myDate" value="${new Date()}" precision="year" years="${2004..2014 }"
              noSelection="['':'-Choose-']"/>
  </td>'

Answer (score 1):

In the controller create the date:

```
def year = new Date().format("yyyy")
def month = new Date().format("MM")
[year:year, month:month]
```

Should give you the current month and year.